# Performance issues after upgrading from asp.net 1.1 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, performance, migration

We have an application which currently runs on Asp.Net 1.1 When we upgraded it to Asp.Net 3.5 we got complaints that the web site was not performing. 
When we looked at the CPU history of the webservers then we see when the site was running on Asp.Net 1.1 the load was max 20%, and with 3.5 the load was around the 40 - 60%

The only thing we did change was the Asp.Net upgrade, and the settings in IIS 6 and the web.config change. In the code we did not change anything.

So what is performing better in 1.1 and not in 3.5? 
(the server is an 2003 webserver)

Comment: The problem is with some code, not with the framework. Try to narrow down the issue to single page causing this problem then post the relevant code.

Comment: If it should be the code then it should be slow under Asp.Net 1.1, right?

Comment: No, there were great many changes in the infrastructure of the framework. For example the old web services are pretty much deprecated in the newer .NET versions (replaced with WCF) so if you're using web services it might affect performance.

Comment: Ok.. we don't use any webservice. But we do call on each page a call via an webrequest:  `Dim hwrequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)` .. Do you know anything else what is pretty much depricated, because its not effecting just one page but all pages

Comment: If you only want to fetch a string from remote URL use the [WebClient.DownloadString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.90).aspx) method which was introduced in .NET 2.0

Comment: No we are posting every time to an url. We do also a lots of reflection and we use Xslt via the GotDotNet.Exslt com object. And we use XML a lot. And we use a lot the AdoDb Component to connect to the DB. Maybe its something to do with one of those items?

Comment: Yes, each of those might be the problem. Looks like you have long debug process ahead, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was (just in case someone would like to know). 
We where using an old dll for ADODB. And the RecordSetClass.Update() was causing the problems. 
In Asp.net 1.1 its not a problem, but in 2.0 and later on its consuming a lots of cpu.